# Trigger react hook after page is completely loaded

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a dynamic html is loaded. I have to remove attribute for header tag.

I am using useEffect but it is calling before the page load. But I need trigger the react hook after the page is completely loaded so that I can do the query selector and remove the attribute.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As a rule `useEffect` will run after render if you add an empty dependency array. But it's hard to say if it will work in your case without seeing any code. Please add a minimal reproducible example of your code with the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

Without a minimal reproducible example, I may suggest the following:
Using `window on load` inside your useEffect, then you can listen to when the page triggers the load event, see something like:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleLoad = () => {
      // this block will run after the entire page has loaded
      console.log('Yo, my page has completely loaded!');
    };

    window.addEventListener('load', handleLoad);

    // Cleanup -> Remove the event listener on unmount
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('load', handleLoad);
    };
  }, []); // this dep array goes empty so it runs only once
```

Crossing fingers this works for you.